# Repeat word in place using regular expression

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

In a text file, I use a `find` to filter the following selection

```
getEnvReadinessConfirmed(
getVersionAvailable(
```

(I use `get\w*\(` to do this)

Is there any way I could duplicate the word after its occurrence as in

```
getEnvReadinessConfirmed(getEnvReadinessConfirmed(
getVersionAvailable(getVersionAvailable(
```

I am looking at http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/add_info/regexp.htm, specifically at

```
{n,}    To repeat n or more times
```

for some hints but unable to get anything working.

Hopefully I am not doing anything terribly stupid but here is the screenshot

[image]

[image]

Greatly appreciate any pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

```
/(get\w+\()\1/
```

[See it working on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/0un1cTuM8q)

Here it is working in Sublime Text 2 (per your question tag).

1. press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
2. press the <kbd>✶</kbd> button in the lower left
3. enter `(get\w+\()\1` in the Search field
4. click <kbd>Find</kbd>

[image: sublime text 2]

---

Here's how to do a Find/Replace using regex

#### before

[image: before]

#### after

[image: after]

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. From your example and from the link, I understand that the `\1` at the end saves us from typing the expression again.  With SublimeText, I am trying to find a single occurrence of a string and duplicate it. I am afraid using the expression in the "replace" box doesn't work (or I am doing something terribly wrong). I am both new to regex and sublimetext. Apologies if regex find/replace is not meant for this purpose.

Comment: Please make sure you click the "Regular Expression" button in the lower left; it looks like `*`. You can also see it highlighted in the image above.

Comment: Updated the question with a screenshot. Is this totally wrong?

Comment: Yikes. I guess I should not be using regex for 'replace'. I dont see any toggles available against the replace textbox.

Comment: Arun, it's fine to use regex for find/replace. What do you want to replace the text with? Replace `getFoo(getFoo(` with just `getFoo(` ?

Comment: Yeah. I am trying to replace `getFoo(` with `getFoo(getFoo(`

Comment: I added some screenshots based on your comment above

Comment: Amazing !! That was spot on. Sorry to have bothered you by not making the question clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this line:

```
(getEnvReadinessConfirmed\()+
```

Which means find your string minimal one time the plus sign is an alias for `{1,}`. Note the backslash before the `(` that masks the bracket so that this char will be searched too.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for

Find: `(get\w+\()`

Replace: `$1$1`

In other words, capture the matched substring in group #1 and replace it with two copies of itself.

That reference you linked to is terrible.  For starters, it's describing a specific regex flavor (the one used by `nnCron`), which is highly unusual in its syntax (e.g. `\b` for start-of-word and `\B` for end-of-word; `(?#...)` for positive lookbehind and `(?~...)` for negative lookbehind).  And while most of the syntax elements are compatible with Perl-style regexes, the docs do a very poor job of describing them.

SublimeText appears to use the Boost regex library for its regex support, so you'd be better off using the [Boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html).  There's also a good tutorial/reference site [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: Precisely. That is what I was looking for. Thanks a ton for the link !!